# Dynamic Interface from own property

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-generics

I wanted to know if this is possible on TypeScript.

I have an interface like this:

```
interface ComplexTable extends BaseTable {
    headers: HeaderOptions[];
    datas: { [id: string]: string }[];
  }
```

And HeaderOptions is just an interface with a label and an id

Is there a way to only allow on datas headers ids given before?

For example I have

```
const table: ComplexTable = {
  headers: [
    { id: 'a', label: 'Name' },
    { id: 'b', label: 'Last Name' },
  ]
}
```

I wan't to only allow on datas objects with only the keys 'a' and 'b'.

This should work

```
const table: ComplexTable = {
  headers: [
    { id: 'a', label: 'Name' },
    { id: 'b', label: 'Last Name' },
  ],
  datas: someData.map((data) => ({
    a: data.someValue,
    b: data.someOtherValue
  }))
}
```

This should not work

```
const table: ComplexTable = {
  headers: [
    { id: 'a', label: 'Name' },
    { id: 'b', label: 'Last Name' },
  ],
  datas: someData.map((data) => ({
    a: data.someValue,
    c: data.someOtherValue
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it's going to take some work:

- You'll need to parameterize `ComplexTable` so it can apply the same rules to its members `headers` and `datas`.
- You'll need to parameterize `HeaderOptions` so it can read the keys out of `id` rather than treating them as a plain `string`.
- You'll need to specify `datas` to take the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `[id in K]`.
- You'll need an identity function [so TypeScript can infer the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61339501/1426891) as you construct the table.

That would look like this:

```
interface HeaderOptions<K> {
  id: K;
  label: string;
}

interface ComplexTable<K extends string> extends BaseTable {
  headers: HeaderOptions<K>[];
  datas: { [id in K]: string }[];
}

function complexTable<K extends string>(table: ComplexTable<K>) {
  return table;
}
```

So you can invoke it like this:

```
const shouldWork = complexTable({
  headers: [
    { id: 'a', label: 'Name' },
    { id: 'b', label: 'Last Name' },
  ],
  datas: someData.map((data) => ({
    a: data.someValue,
    b: data.someOtherValue
  }))
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3mpBbEAIlBlAFzwCCMMUAngDwDeO+AalBAK4jmYwCWKAOYBubHhAB5DAAsQMdlx7YMA4QF8AfCICwAKEEZ5AMyhgEAIShoQAFSgAjCAkbr9+gPQf4AWj9hODD8fdwMUIxhTc3gACRAoUBhJAAcMflQ0egBpTXhGfXh4fmByLN09QugHEAheVUFRfTc9fUMTMwQAYTxk5wAPeycQbPgQPqMUYDQVNSFcsYmp+CsbQec8gvg5BPk0cjidpNT09GzNAG0AXXLC4GJrckZ4c+KilHgsy7rZ+HUr8ua+mMnBQYDSqEQPX6a2GWVG4xAk2mfAamgAFCQhuRurhemMYWcAJR5eBwDCcGDvTHOMSAvTIdBYNAyJCcCDAADqSBgAGt4ABeSG46GOZxo-IVeBeQoAPQA-Jttok9s9NoVpfK1STiuQAORQXUAGngVRqeoAclB8LrfoatU8dfBdQ4jSbHGanQAZaxYS3W22bS52yV3EgqliEe4AOlwUGSaLRoagxP5uXFWq8mslhTI8CTUYjim4wcKhQc5HzEekcgUHG4m3UhMJTUJ5X0DMw2BZbOA5qQGC5vIFQrxA1FIHTkqVu3I53tRRKToNxtNtSdfpANvUJdLDsXztdq713s7G63O6DmyT4YkRBIMbjCaTKbTEtL8FzlYkRZAO8KYAraMq1keQfwbJsWzbPRpVsWhkhAABlMABFSPMkBANAUF1LBcEEYAimMeBaFZGA83uaYkAcAArcAsBkax4AwJAkHgWMUFoeBkhgJB4JgNIMKjQT2wyLAQTGeCwRAYA7ygQceWmQVkGFfFx0nQppxgFU52zbV92XN1qjXXUzwDSVLxDcjeFvaNY3jRN7hfeA1NLT8gO-Otfy1ACyPvYCazAyVG2bPRGyg6VBKjBxAiKLBgHQ6ZcMmeAAHc5CpOROO43j+OmWAEFwtA0AaKNhMZVj+EKhoZIIeK+wHbk+UUqEVKGZyNK0+dHX1Q93SMkzt06-cXRXXrjx9eB+ovHdrys-AZIfOznwFV8tVc3z3KUHcgsgoA)

Note that, as in the playground, TypeScript won't mind if you supply more data keys than it knows to expect in the `headers`; however, it will complain if any of the data keys is missing.